# How to join fields of two tables using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I have two tables and related Java mapping.

```
CREATE TABLE country (
    code VARCHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE user (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    country_code VARCHAR(3),
    FOREIGN KEY ( country_code ) REFERENCES country ( code )
);
```

Here is my Java entities. Country POJO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
public class Country {

    @Id
    @Column (name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Column (name = "name")
    private String name;
```

And User POJO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "country_code")
    private String countryCode;
```

Question is how can I join `Contry.code` to `User.countryCode` in Hibernate using annotation? When I create User object with Hibernate I need to bind these two fields (code and countryCode) automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `@OneToMany` mapping from `Country` to `User` entity and corresponding `@ManyToOne` mapping from `User` to `Country`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
public class Country {

    @Id
    @Column (name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Column (name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "country")
    private Set<User> users;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_code")
    private Country country;
}
```

Comment: But I need just a countryCode not Country object.

Comment: @user3279337 This is how you create mapping between entities in hibernate. You can get `countryCode` from the `country` reference.

Comment: @user3279337 BTW, this is just a very basic mapping. There are many more options you can give. You might want to go through hibernate documentation for more information on this.