# Joining Two Tables using Hibernate Annotations

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm having some trouble understanding how to join tables together using Hibernate annotations. I'm hoping to get a simple working example to get a better understanding...

So I have two objects mapped to tables:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOANS")
public class Loan {

    @Id
    @Column(name="LOAN_ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="REQUESTAMOUNT")
    private String requestAmount;

    @Column(name="STATUS_ID")
    private Integer statusId

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "LOAN_STATUS")
public class LoanStatus {

    @Id
    @Column(name="STATUS_ID")
    private Integer statusId;

    @Column(name="STATUS_DESCRIPTION")
    private String statusDescription;

}
```

And basically what I'm trying to find is all information for a given "loan" (including the statusDescription in the LoanStatus table) where Loan.statusId = LoanStatus.statusId. How can I accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: This is fundamental stuff. Why don't you read the hibernate manual? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  mapping in pojo according to your table structure `(@OneToMany/ @ManyToOne/@ManyToMany)` from LoanStatus to Loan entity and corresponding `(@OneToMany/ @ManyToOne/@ManyToMany)` mapping from Loan to LoanStatus :

Like:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "STATUS_ID")
private Set<User> Loan;
-----------------------------------
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "STATUS_ID")
private LoanStatus loanStatus ;
```

You can check this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334630/how-to-join-fields-of-two-tables-using-hibernate)